# Need help reading piano sheet music

Tags: piano, sheet-music

I'm a newbie and trying to make this piece of music in FL Studio, but I'm having trouble reading this piano sheet. How am I supposed to read the parts where the notes are zigzagging with each other like this?

[image: sheet music]

I reckon they need to be played in order, but still, I don't know exactly when to play the notes. And also what do these small gaps (2) mean? Are they rests and how can I know how long they are? Big thanks, I appreciate any help.

Comment: I wouldn't waste my time trying to decipher this lousy job - except someone were puzzler lie me ;) if not: back to the sender!

Comment: tat crzay nottion isst wat dey meenwidit donno bitsme ask whu rotit

Comment: This goes a long way towards the notion that 4/4 bars ought to be written so they can be seen in two equal parts. Or is it 3/4 or maybe four-and-a- half/four? And notes played together really ought to be vertically aligned. This certainly takes you-tube items to greater depths!

Comment: @Tim: good thought! I get sometimes similar pictures when the time is set wrong. Somehow I think I should know this song, but I can't remember it right now. Could it be https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pHQAGmo6ZM

Comment: Aside from the already noted mistakes, there should be no vertical line right after the clefs. Generally, this sheet looks very suspicious…

Comment: Every single bar of this contains at least one mistake. Return to sender.

Comment: This sheet music is horrifying. Please remember to mark a correct answer if you think one did properly answer your question.

Answer (score 13):

I am not a great specialist in music notation, but there is something awfully wrong with this piano sheet. For example in the third measure the sum of the values of the notes in treble clef is less than one, whereas in bass clef it is one. The fourth measure where you marked "1" in the bass clef, the sum of the note values is 1 1/4. I have never seen anything alike. Where did you get the piano sheet from?

Small gaps (2) aren't supposed to mean anything.

Actually you should not look at the vertical alignment (zigzags) of the notes (though normally it should be consistent). When they are played is completely determined in the clef they are in (i.e. all the pauses and required lengths are already there).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the tips too. I wish have enought reputation to give an upvote to you

Comment: One *ought* to be able to determine where notes come, timing-wise, as notes of same or different lengths that start together are normally vertical to each other. However, this sheet is anything *but* normal..!

Comment: Sadly, this sheet is not such an exception. Such errors do occur, and when they do, you are either left with buying a better sheet, or trying to figure out the *intention* of the author at that point.

Answer (score 8):

You can't READ this page, because the notation is illiterate.  All you can do is try to work out what the person who created this mess intended!

It's reasonably clear what order the notes come in, and when the RH and LH notes coincide.  From there in, you'll have to do some guessing I'm afraid.

(later)  It seems you know the song.  So, using this as a guide, it shouldn't be too hard for you to write a better score.  Then do the world a favour and post it wherever you found this one!

Comment: Ahh thanks a LOT. I was suspicious that the sheet is written wrong, like it can't be that HARD, but I wasn't sure. Now I can move on, shame this is my favourite song (Vietnamese), I found only this sheet on Youtube.

Comment: @user1996mkl Some of us are interested in knowing the song you're trying to transcribe. Could you answer it on [this question on Music Fans Stack Exchange](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/9940)?

Answer (score 4):

This sheet is - as OP declares in the answer to a comment - a vietnamese song he copy from Youtube.

> Ahh thanks a LOT. I was suspicious that the sheet is written wrong, like it can't be that HARD, but I wasn't sure. Now I can move on, shame this is my favourite
> song (Vietnamese), I found only this sheet on Youtube.

**It seems to be a midifile that has been imported in a notation program with a false time setting.**

If we had the

a) the title of the song or

b) the midifile or

c) the youtube link from which OP has this incredible copy

we could and would like help.

**Edit:**

I think I’ve got it!

**This is the result of a wave to midi conversion or mp3 to sheet music transcription software.**

As we can see these apps are still lightyears away from what you can learn in a few hours:

Play this simple tune by ear

Learn reading sheet music by writing it down

the rhythm doesn’t have to be as it is song. You can notate it in simple 4th notes! Starting in bar three with up beat:

mi/midodola/re,,re/retitiso/do,,do/ladorere/ti,,fa/famidore/mi etc.

Probably the chords of the l.h. (harmony / accompaniment) is post pond: look at bar 5!

We recognize the progression Am,,,Dm,,,G7,,,C,,, (root, fifth, octave: 1,5,8) that fits fine to the melody phrase above.

Again to the rhythm: mind that notation will never be 100% identical with the performance and vice versa, that means also a professional writer will never write notate music exactly how it is meant to be played, while a midi-notating program will be able to do so ... but nobody would be able to read it!